B and W film from the 1950s about a man having crush on a redhead
Does anyone know the name of an old film about a man who meets a redhead at a party and falls in love with her? He then spends all his life looking for her and only going on dates with similar looking ladies.
Eventually at the end of the film when married and much older he meets the same woman again at a party while chatting up a younger version of her. Sadly he fails to recognise her as his first love.
I saw the film about 25 years ago. I cannot recall who the actors were in it sadly nor the name.

How do you know she was a redhead?

I would assume it's in the dialogue

In this case it was in the title :-)

But how would you know she is, in fact, a redhead?? hmm..

I believe the film you're looking for is the 1955 film The Man Who Loved Redheads. 
One of the plot summaries almost perfectly matches your description. Great memory for a movie you watched 25 years ago! 
Plot Summary (From IMDb):

When just a young boy, Lord Binfield briefly met and fell in love with redheaded-teenager Sylvia. He never forgot her face despite having gotten married and raised a family as well as having assumed his title and a position with the foreign office. One day on the street he meets a young woman who so resembles Sylvia that he asks her to dinner, posing as a bachelor and borrowing the use of the apartment of his friend, Oscar, and also the use of Oscar's man-servant Williams. He likes the excitement and decides to lead a double life so he can dabble-and-dilly with the opposite sex at will. Over the years, all of his dabbling-and-dilling are with women who resemble Sylvia. At one of his parties, his son Dennis shows up but Binfield persuades him to keep his secret. He and Oscar grow old but still go for an occasional fling, the latest being to take two models to the opening night of a show in which Dennis appears. He is startled to find his wife, Caroline, present and in the know about his young girlfriends and also his other escapades through the years. He is overwhelmed by her loyalty and affection and resolves to stray no more. He doesn't even recognize childhood-love Sylvia standing nearby, for she, too, has grown old.
  - Les Adams 


@alexanderthethrd You seem to have created two separate user accounts. If you merge them by following the instructions here, you'll then be able to accept this answer as the correct one by clicking the checkmark on the left (only visible when you're logged into the same account you used to post the question).
